# Stop flexslider animating reverse on mouse wheel scroll

Tags: jquery, flexslider, mousewheel

I'm using horizontal 'flexslider' with mouse wheel enabled. I don't want to reverse / loop the animation. I applied few properties in flexslider.

`animationLoop: false` 
`reverse: false`

Here is my slider function

```
    $('.solutionSlider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            animationLoop: false,
            slideshow: false,
            controlNav: false,
            reverse: false,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            slideshowSpeed: 0,
            animationSpeed: 1000,
            directionNav: false,
            itemWidth: 168,
            itemMargin: 28,
            touch: true,
            mousewheel: true
        });
```

It is working for the swipe functionality. But when I scroll the slider with mouse wheel It is animating back to the first slide when I reach the last one. I searched all the blogs, documents etc.. but I didn't found any solution.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/657

Comment: @Zl3n sorry, I didn't mean loop. It shouldn't animate in reverse direction when it reached last slide. Edited the question please check